# Почему фраза в шаблоне не перевелась?

Tags: django

Я не понимаю, почему в шаблоне одна фраза была переведена, а вторая - нет?
С чем это может быть связано?

```
python manage.py makemessages
python manage.py compilemessages
```

**settings**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
    ('kk', gettext('Kazakh')),
)

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ru'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

'solid_i18n.middleware.SolidLocaleMiddleware',

SOLID_I18N_USE_REDIRECTS = True
```

**template**

```
{% load l10n i18n %}

<div>{% trans credit.creditpayment_set.first.security %}</div>        #It's translated
<div>{% trans credit.creditpayment_set.first.comission_name_type %}</div>  #It's not translated
```

**django.po (ru)**

## security

```
#: credits/models.py:70
msgid "Pledge - real estate"
msgstr "залог - имеющееся недвижимость"
```

## comission_type

```
#: credits/models.py:156
msgid "For consideration"
msgstr "Комиссия за рассмотрения"
```

**models.py**

```
SECURITY_WITHOUT = 'Without collateral and guarantee'
SECURITY_REAL = 'Pledge - real estate'

SECURITY_CHOICES = (
    (SECURITY_WITHOUT, _('Without collateral and guarantee')),
    (SECURITY_REAL, _('Pledge - real estate')),
)

class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION = 'for consideration'
    COMISSION_TYPE_ORGANIZATION = 'for organization'

    COMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION, _('For consideration')),
        (COMISSION_TYPE_ORGANIZATION, _('For organization')),
    )

credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
security = models.CharField(_('security'), max_length=255, choices=SECURITY_CHOICES, default=SECURITY_WITHOUT)
comission_name_type = models.CharField(_('comission name type'), max_length=255, choices=COMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES, default=COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION, blank=True, null=True)
```

Собственно, на выходе должны быть переводы из **django.po**. В первом случае перевод есть, а во втором я получаю `for consideration`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, модели, в которых используется эти строки

Comment: Добавил код модели.

Comment: Удивлюсь, если дело в том, что `COMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES` находится внутри модели.

Comment: Покажите данные модели, ожидаемый результат и фактический результат, а то непонятно ничего. А ещё у вас в коде переменная COMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES никак не используется, а переменная COMISSION_CHOICES не существует

Comment: @andreymal Поправил код...

Comment: У вас в модели строка для ключа написана `for consideration` и в шаблоне выводится тоже она, а в файле django.po написано `For consideration` — это разные строки, поэтому и не переводится

Comment: Для вывода choices можно использовать get_<field>_display()
`credit.creditpayment_set.first.get_comission_name_type_display`
Если это вам подойдет, оформлю как ответ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730211/how-does-get-field-display-in-django-work

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. @ZaArs можете оформить.

Comment: @ZaArs проблема в том, что вопрос не о выводе choices, а о переводе. В итоге с таким ответом здесь устроится бардак

Comment: @andreymal так сработало ведь... Только я ещё в `trans` обернул.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 заворачивать в trans неправильно, потому что вы уже завернули всё в `_()` в коде модели

Comment: @andreymal я посоветовал как сделать лучше. ибо зачем изобретать велосипед из костылей, когда имеется готовый механизм как раз для таких целей

Comment: @ZaArs я ни в коем случае не спорю, что это лучше, но вопрос не об этом, и это всё устраивает бардак в базе знаний

Comment: то есть, вы предлагаете в модели изменить `For` на `for`? И заново прокатить `makemessages`?

Comment: В вашем случае да, @m0nte-cr1st0 предлагает имеено это, ключи и переводимое значение должны совпадать. Если записей в БД нет, лучше заменить ключ с `for` на `For`. Если же в БД есть записи и не можете по какой либо причине из обновить, то `For`  на `for`. Ну и присмотритесь к моему варианту

Comment: @andreymal Только та же строка `{% trans credit.creditpayment_set.first.security %}` без `trans` не переводится. Хотя там ведь всё совпадает...

Comment: Даже не знаю, чей вариант лучше...

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 в вашем случае не переводилось, потому что строка `for consideration` как раз НЕ была завёрнута в `_()` (Za Ars всё правильно написал как надо выводить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поясняю за всех, что касается вашего вопроса, дабы не публиковать ответы в комментах.

В объектах модели choices поля выводятся 2мя способами: как ключ и как значение
Вы выводите его как ключ, то есть то, что находится в `SECURITY_WITHOUT` и `COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION`.

Если обратить внимание на код

```
class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION = 'for consideration'
    COMISSION_TYPE_ORGANIZATION = 'for organization'

    COMISSION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION, _('For consideration')),
        (COMISSION_TYPE_ORGANIZATION, _('For organization')),
    )
```

То мы видим, что значение `COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION = 'for consideration'` не совпадает первым символом с `_('For consideration')`

Из-за этого в шаблоне вы пытаетесь перевести строку  `'for consideration'`, для которой нет перевода.

Решения два:

1. Как предложил @andreymal обновить ключ на `COMISSION_TYPE_CONSIDERATION = 'For consideration'` либо строку перевода на `_('for consideration')`
2. использовать метод get_FIELD_display (более правильный)

```
{% load l10n i18n %}

<div>{{ credit.creditpayment_set.first.get_security_display }}</div>  
<div>{{ trans credit.creditpayment_set.first.get_comission_name_type_display }}
</div>
```